# Search API specification

Tags: spring-boot

Hi Hoping to get some help, I have a table like this

```
status  senderbank  receiverbank
Completed   HDFC     SBI
Queued  SBI         HDFC
Failed  SBI         ICICI
```

I am able to get the details if user enter the bank name it compares either with senderBank or ReceiverBank.But if the status is queued It should compare only with senderBank.Ex: user try to search  HDFC it should get only first record ie

```
status  senderbank  receiverbank
Completed   HDFC       SBI
```

Below is the code I have tried:

```
public Specification<Entity> hasBankName(String bankName) {

return (root,query,cb) -> cb.or(cb.equals(root.get("senderBank"), bankName),cb.equal(root.get("receiverBank"), bankName));
```

Someone please help me how to modify the above code when status is queued.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This `specification` should work:

```
(root,query,cb) -> cb.and(cb.or(cb.equals(root.get("senderBank"), bankName), cb.equal(root.get("receiverBank"), 
                          cb.notEqual(root.get("status"), "Queued"))))
```

Comment: Thanks@Jonathan. But the requirement is If I enter SBI it should return 

'status  senderbank  receiverbank
Completed   HDFC     SBI
Queued  SBI         HDFC
Failed  SBI         ICICI'

 If banker name is receiver bank and status is queued it should not return that record but if bank name is sender bank then it should return all the records including status = queued